# Python: calling a private method within static method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, static-methods, private-methods

What is the correct way and best practice to call a private method from within a static method in **`python 3.x`**? See example below:

```
class Class_A:
    def __init__(self, some_attribute):
        self.some_attr = some_attribute

    def __private_method(arg_a):
        print(arg)
    
    @staticmethod
    def some_static_method(arg_a):
        __private_method(arg_a) # "__private_method" is not defined
```

Now, if I instantiate a `Class_A` object and call the static method:

```
my_instance = Class_A("John Doe")
my_instance.some_static_method("Not his real name")
```

I get a NameError: `NameError: name '__private_method' is not defined`

Comment: Static method is independent of instances. How do you expect it to access the private method of instance?

Comment: Even if I add `@staticmethod` atop the private method, it remains inaccessible?

Comment: 1. There is no such thing as `@static_method`, you meant `@staticmethod` 2. Don't use leading double underscore.

Comment: the problem is that you are trying to access `__private_method` as a global method but it's part of `Class_A` if you want to call it you need to use the Class_A or an instance of it.
```
class Class_A:
    def __init__(self, some_attribute):
        self.some_attr = some_attribute
    @staticmethod
    def __private_method(arg_a):
        print(arg_a)
    
    @staticmethod
    def some_static_method(arg_a):
        Class_A.__private_method(arg_a)
``` i know the output is messed up but it will work